# Spotfire - How to buid a sequencial number based on Date and Time

Tags: date, time, spotfire, rank

I'm trying to assign a sequential number to a set of data based on Date and Time below an example:

```
Name  Date        Time   Expected Result
Alex  02/12/2018  10:30  2
Alex  02/12/2018  21:00  3
Alex  02/07/2018  07:00  1
Jhon  03/03/2018  09:31  2
Jhon  03/03/2018  09:30  1
```

I tried using the Rank function but without success.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rank() can have an additional column argument that lets you group by it. So
the expression:

Rank(ToEpochSeconds([Date]) + ToEpochSeconds([Time]),[Name])

should give you the same as the Expected Result:
first argument says you want to rank by the combination of Date and Time, second argument says you want to group by Name.

The ToEpochSeconds should take into account the different date formats and turn both Date and Time into integers before adding them.

Gaia

Comment: Hi Gaia, Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it seems not working. This is what I got.

Comment: 1 - 2 - 3 - 2 - 1

Comment: instead of 2 - 3 - 1 - 2 - 1

Comment: I suspect the CONCATENATE statement is treating Date and Time as String.

Comment: I edited the answer. Indeed the Concatenate worked in my time zone because of the different date format. I tested on US dates and it seems to work now

Comment: Hi Gaia, It seems working well now. Thank you very much for your help. ;-)

Comment: Great - a reminder to always double check when dates are involved. Can you please accept the answer? Thanks. Gaia